# Prove that function between congruence classes is well defined

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f:\mathbf{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbf{Z}_m : [x]_n \mapsto [x]_m$. Prove that $f$ is well defined if $m\mid n$.

We need to prove two things:

1. For all $\alpha\in \mathbf{Z}_n$, there exists $\beta\in \mathbf{Z}_m$ such that $f(\alpha)=\beta$.
2. For all $\alpha\in \mathbf{Z}_n$, if $f(\alpha)=y$ and $f(\alpha)=z$ then $y=z$.

I don't know how to prove the first one.. The second one I was able to prove.

Let $\alpha=[x]_n=[x']_n \in \mathbf{Z}_n$. Then $f(\alpha)=[x]_m$ and $f(\alpha)=[x']_m$. We need to prove that $[x]_m=[x']_m$.

$[x]_n=[x']_n$ gives $n\mid x-x'$ or $x-x'=nk$ for some $k\in \mathbf{Z}$. But $m\mid n$, so $n=\ell m$ for some $\ell\in \mathbf{Z}$. Combining those two gives $x-x'=\ell m k$ or $m\mid x-x'$ so $[x]_m=[x']_m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m\mid n$ then $m\leq n$. Thus, every $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ will have a residue mod $m$; that is, there exists $\beta\in \mathbb{Z}_m$ such that $f(\alpha)=\beta$. In the second item you actually proved that $\beta$ does not depend in the choice of a representative for $\alpha$. Therefore, $f$ is well-defined.